# Unity，When I package an empty scene, the GPU usage reaches 100%！！！

Tags: 3d

[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tfXx.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orTud.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C67tO.png)

I didn't do anything, just packed an empty scene, with this graphics card it reached 100%

I used Unity 2021, 2019, 2017 have the same problem, what is the problem?

Comment: You are using a super old version of Unity, upgrade and see if you still have the problem